# Can children appear in a porn movie if they're not exposed to any sexual act?

Tags: minor, pornography

Hope it doesn't sound too creepy. Just watched a R-Rated regular movie with children actors that, even having participated, would not be allowed to watch it in the cinema (for being too violent, scary, mature, etc.)
That left me wondering if it would be legal (bizarre as it may be) for somebody to do a porn movie were children appear, not doing or witnessing any sexual-related activities (of course), i.e. an everyday scene where a mother takes her son to the school and when she returns home... let's say that the action of this kind of movies begins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant US law is 18 [USC Chapter 110](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-110). The law forbids minors depicted as engaging in "sexually explicit conduct", or forbids ["child pornography"](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2256), the latter section also defining "sexually explicit conduct". A minor appearing in a movie containing porn is not prohibited.